# Change the original file's path in a PDB file

Tags: c#, debugging, teamcity, nuget

We use Team City as a build server. We have Team City configured to create a couple of nuget packages (including pdb files for debugging) from one of our solutions whenever it is built.

The problem is that whenever Team City builds the solution, it generates pdb files with hard coded source file locations inside (something along the lines of `c:\TeamCity\Builds\{guid}\Path\To\Source\File.cs`).

As all of our developers use the same folder structure for the location of their solutions, it is possible to predict where this file should be. So my question is: Is it possible to provide Team City with the location of the solution's root directory as it would be found on a developer's machine? Maybe a value in web.config, or in the .nuspec file?

Comment: No.  Just use the same directory structure on your build machine.  The normal way this is done is by also making your build machine the symbol server.